# What is the meaning of the angle bracket notations in OllyDbg's hex dump display?

Tags: debugging, assembly

In OllyDbg, main disassembly view (and other disassembly views) there are angle bracket notations and a dash notation (> v - etc). What is the meaning of these notations. For example, in the screen shot below the line at 73DA has a ">" notation. The line above has a dot followed by a caron, etc.

[image: OllyDbg Screenshot extract]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^ v` arrows indicate the direction of a branch/jump. Notice that they only appear on `J__` (jump) instructions: if the target address comes before that instruction, an up-arrow will appear; if the target address comes after that instruction, a down-arrow will appear.

The `>` arrow indicates that it's a target of such instructions. For instance, take the line at `010073B9`. There's a down-arrow because the jump target is `010073DA`, which comes after `010073B9`. Then, there's a `>` at `010073DA` because it's targeted by the jump.

In other words, they're just visual aids. They serve no syntactic purpose.

Comment: What is the dash ("-") symbol for?

Comment: They look more like dots to me, but it seems like they don't indicate anything special.